# Streaming video/audio from iOS device

Tags: ios, audio, video, streaming, video-streaming

I have read several posts here about live streaming video/audio from iOS device while user is recording. Unfortunately it seems that there is not any "good" solution.

I understand that I must have access to files while I am recording and then send files to server from which other users can watch my stream live (with a small time lag).

Working with iOS is not problem for me, I am more struggling with part where data should be handled to server and the whole processing on server.

I have several questions:

1. Saying just server is very vague, what "kind of" server it should be?
2. I understand that I must use some protocol to send data **TO** server and then to get data **FROM** server so user can watch live video, what protocol should I use?
3. I feel very lost with whole server side processing, what should be done with files that were sent to server?
4. All this seems to be very nontrivial is there any third party solution? For example what technology apps like Periscope, Ustream or Meerkat use to provide live stream feature for their users?

I would also really appreciate if possible answers would more than one word long for each question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please find my answers to your questions:

1. There is a class of software called "media servers". E.g. Wowza, Red5, Nimble Streamer, nginx-rtmp-module and a few others.
2. Most common protocols for sending data TO media server are RTMP and RTSP. Watching the video is done via several ones like RTMP (requires Flash installed), HLS (native for iOS, supported by Android 4+, working on some web-players), DASH (supported by some players).
3. No files needed, media server can process incoming live stream and handle connections from viewers.
4. Basically they use combination of mentioned technologies plus their own "know-how".

Comment: So I can use wowza media server as my back-end. Then using RTMP and RTSP I will send files I am capturing with my camera to wowza and for watching live stream in iOS I will use Http Live Streaming (since it is restriction by Apple)? And I guess that every information I need is in wowza documentation, right?

Comment: Please answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33889683/how-to-implemet-digital-picture-frame-in-ios-app if you can..